# How can I use tensorflow-gpu?

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, nvidia

I am trying to use my GPU for keras-tensorflow. But I couldn't find a GPU.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPU Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

Output: Num GPU Available:  0

When I try to find CPU,

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num CPU Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('CPU')))
```

Output: Num CPU Available:  1

Can someone explain what is the difference? How can I use my GPU? I have 2 "GT 750M" GPU.

I installed CUDA v10.1 and cuDNN-10.1-windows7-x64-v7.6.5.32.zip. Also I am using tensorflow 1.14.0 and numpy 1.16.4

Comment: You need to have CUDA installed and the correct version of cuDNN that TF recognises for the install version you have. Also note that certain versions of CUDA may not support the compute capability of your card so TF in GPU mode may still not work.

Comment: I already installed CUDA and cuDNN. I guess my GPU is not enough. Can you explain what is the difference between CPU and GPU? Can I use CPU for image processing?

Comment: have you installed `tensorflow` or `tensorflow-gpu`?

Comment: Yes, I have. I am using tensorflow 1.14.0.

Comment: Tensorflow 2.x automatically uses GPU or CPU depending on if the hardware is compatible and if you have CUDA installed. There is no longer a separate install you need to use. Why are you not using 2.x?

Comment: @codcod4 The Tensorflow API does not change between CPU and GPU.  In an API viewpoint, there is no difference in setting up the network, training and testing.  What is different is the computational throughput achieved during training.  GPUs are exceptionally good at performing calculations in parallel at high speeds.  This is basically what is done when training a neural network as it requires backpropagation and you're updating the weights with batches of examples.  Therefore, training on CPU is exceptionally slower vs. GPU.  You can train a network using CPU but it will take a long time.